# Why are screeners released in DVD format instead of Blu-ray?

Tags: production, distribution, marketing

> A screener (SCR) is an advance screening of a film or television
>   series sent to critics, awards voters, video stores (for their manager
>   and employees), and other film industry professionals, including
>   producers and distributors.
>   [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screener)

From what I see in torrent sites, screeners are often released in DVD format.

Why won't film makers send screeners in Blu-ray discs, at least for a better visual on the film since Blu-ray video has a higher resolution than DVDs? Also IMO, the Blu-ray disk may have better protections to prevent the movie from being copied or ripped.

Comment: *"..prevent the movie from being copied or ripped."* The only way to achieve that is to ***not distribute it to anyone.*** Once it's out there, people will be able to steal it. If I was distributing movies, I'd like the (1st) illegal versions to be of lower quality (and with a big watermark in the middle of the screen).

Comment: My bet is that it's because DVD is pretty much standard at this point (if you're still using VHS, you can't rent much these days...), but Blu-Ray has not gained complete acceptance.  For many, DVD is still a great experience.  For that reason, why would you distribute something your audience might not be able to watch, if your sole intention is to get them to watch your movie and vote for you?

Comment: They are also sent out on Blu-ray and even streaming: http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/race/oscar-academy-awards-screeners-rules-247434

Comment: Maybe your torrent site only has access to the DVD version... doesn't mean that higher res versions don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> "From what I see on torrent sites..."

I'd guess that the quality is enough for what's needed for screeners to screen and review a movie, and the format makes pirated versions that circulate before DVD release less appealing and less likely to take business away from a more high-definition experience in the theater and when it eventually gets to Blu-ray.